# How to get file type of selected item in CTreeCtrl? The file name extensions may be hidden, so GetItemText is not helpful

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I'm taking over an old project built with MFC. I'm not familiar with MFC at all, but I need to add a few new features to this project.

There is a tree list in the program, showing files on your computer. Double-click an item and the corresponding file will be imported into the project. At first, I used the following code to get the selected file name:

```
HTREEITEM hSelectItem = m_wndTree.GetSelectedItem();
CString filename = m_wndTree.GetItemText(hSelectItem);
```

But later, the method failed on others' computers, because they may check *hide file name extensions* so a file named "Arial.ttf" will return "Arial".

What is the best way for me to the full path of a selected item? inherit CTreeCtrl and override some functions may be a choice, but not familiar with MFC can cost me a lot of time and will get hands dirty. Are there any APIs or third-party libraries I can use?

Besides, The actual class I'm using is CMFCShellTreeCtrl, which has a public method GetItemPath, but there is a bug in it so I can't use this method to get the full path.

Thanks!

Comment: Be more explicit, it's hard to understand what you want.

Comment: If your question is *"Can I safely write code without learning target platform?"* then the answer is: No. The remainder of the question is beyond comprehensibility.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Is it explicit now? Please take a look at my new description.

Comment: @IInspectable I'm sorry but English is not my first language. I've modified the description, maybe it is clearer now.

Comment: A `CTreeCtrl` is a generic control, it's not designed specifically for navigating a file-system and so doesn't have the concept of "full filesystem path for an item" as a native part of the tree. This meaning is given to it by the application that hosts the control.

Comment: What exactly is that bug in `CMFCShellTreeCtrl::GetItemPath` you refering to ?

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thanks for your comment! I've been searching for how to get full path from CTreeCtrl all day long. Now I realize I'm wrong.

Comment: @MichaelWalz If the selected item is a directory, the method works well and returns the full path; but if it is a file, the method returns an empty string, which means an error. The bug seems to be fixed in a later version of VS, but due to some reasons, I can't port the old project to new version of VS. Is it possible to get the source code of CMFCShellTreeCtrl so that I can override the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about [this bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/522686/cmfcshelltreectrl-getitempath-returns-empty-string), it was fixed back in 2010, so it should be resolved starting with MSVC 2012, I guess. If you need to work with MSVC 2010, then you might consider overriding the original `CMFCShellTreeCtrl` and replacing the buggy `GetItemPath` with the current implementation which you can easily take from a current compiler version.

Comment: Yes, it is! Your answer is really helpful. I'll try it now.

Comment: I finally solved the problem. I replaced the GetItemPath, but it still returned an empty string. Then I found that the method calls BindToObject and an error occurs. I tried commenting the call, and everything works fine, so I got the full path. I don't know why, but my problem is solved. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The control has SetItemData and GetItemData methods that it inherits from CTreeCtrl. So when the control is being populated you can put the full file name or path into a heap-allocated string (CString) and save the address of the string with SetItemData. Then you can get it back when an item is clicked.